# Disable Dialog in EditTextPreference, Launch Intent Instead

Tags: android, google-drive-api, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

I'm trying to write an app using the Google Drive SDK.  I'd like to use a Preference object in a PreferenceActivity that allows the user to select the Google account that they want to upload files to.  I've been trying to use an EditTextPreference to launch the account picker intent.  It works.  However, after selecting the account, the EditText dialog appears.  Is it possible to disable the dialog?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="@string/title_upload_category">
    <EditTextPreference
      android:title="@string/title_upload_acct"
      android:key="@string/key_upload_acct"/>
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

PrefsFragment

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate) {
  GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
  EditTextPreference acctValue = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.key_upload_acct));
  acctValue.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), 1);
        return false;
    }               
  });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
      String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
      acctValue.setSummary(accountName);
      acctValue.setText(accountName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything correct except you should use a Preference instead of an EditTextPreference. Then the dialog won't show up, and the functionality of the preference is handled by you when you set the onPreferenceClickListener.

Comment: Thanks!  (I was actually planning on entering a comment saying I was going to do exactly what you described.  Glad to hear that it is the right way to go).  One more question though.  I was handling saving the preference by using SharedPreferences.Editor.putString, since there is no Preference.setText method.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yea thats correct. You will have to set the preference manually.